# Android, Silent mode notification

Tags: android

In my android app I need to know, whenever the user is in Phone options mode (the one that appears when you hold down the power button for a while), and pushes the 'Silent mode' button. I have found that Airplane mode is linked to the `ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED`. But I can not find any action event for the 'Silent mode' button?

Answer (score 4):

The `AudioManager` provides a `getRingerMode()` method which can be used to determine the current state.
In your case you have to query the returned value for `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT`, so something like

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

if (am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
    // do something neat here
}
```

In combination with AudioManager's `RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION` this should work for you