# Android Notifications with no sound

Tags: android, audio, notifications, volume, silent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android, Silent mode notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242873/android-silent-mode-notification)

How do I ensure that my notification will be delivered silently?

Is there a way to set the sound to "off" when creating the notification, or will I have to do something like turning the system notification volume off right before the notification arrives and then restoring volume after the notification has been delivered?

Comment: Notifications are created via NotificationManager or NotificationBuilder, and both accepts sound (defined by sound URI) to play when the Notification is displayed. Have you tried to set this URI to null? Another way would be to create a silent sound and pass that URI.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this -

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if (am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) 
{
    // do something neat here
}
```

And, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242873/android-silent-mode-notification)